# Converting a HashMap Object to ResultSet

Tags: java, json, hashmap, resultset

I know its silly to ask but we have huge legacy code which expects ResultSet for processing data, but we have created another API which gets Data in JSON format. I'm converting the JSON object to HashMap and pass the HashMap object to the legacy code for DataProcessing. Since legacy code always expects ResultSet I'm not able to process new data.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a custom implementation of the [`Interface ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to subclass ResultSet to create another class that can be created with data other than the result of a SQL query, by adding methods that add data.

If this is too complex or time consuming for you, as it was for me, you can find one that somebody else has already written and published.

I have successfully used Mockrunner:

http://mockrunner.github.io

Here's how I implemented it:

Create a class with a static method to return a ResultSet from a header list and a data array:

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;

import com.mockrunner.mock.jdbc.MockResultSet;

public class OkResultSet {

public static ResultSet getResultSet(List<String> headers, List<List<Object>> data) throws Exception 
{
    if (headers == null || data == null) {
        throw new Exception("null parameters");
    }

    List<Object> firstList = data.get(0);

    if (headers.size() != firstList.size()) {
        throw new Exception("parameter sizes are not equal");
    }

    MockResultSet mockResultSet = new MockResultSet("okResultSet");

    for (String string : headers) {         
        mockResultSet.addColumn(string);
    }

    for (List<Object> list : data) {
        mockResultSet.addRow(list);
    }

    return mockResultSet;
    }
}
```

Construct a header list and a data array within my code and call the new method to create a ResultSet that I can then pass to the legacy code:

```
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
headers.add("Question");
headers.add("ResponseType");
headers.add("ChecklistType");
headers.add("Required");

List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < questionArray.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject questionObject = (JSONObject)questionArray.get(i);
    String question = (String)questionObject.get("Question");
    String responseType = (String)questionObject.get("ResponseType");
    String checklistType = (String)questionObject.get("ChecklistType");
    String required = (String)questionObject.get("Required");

    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    objects.add(question);
    objects.add(responseType);
    objects.add(checklistType);
    objects.add(required);
    data.add(objects);
}

ResultSet finalResultSet = null;
try {
    finalResultSet = OkResultSet.getResultSet(headers, data);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.warn("parseJobsetForChecklistQuestions | error "+e.getMessage());
}
```